# Printing value next to text box from a function in flask html

Tags: python, flask

I am having below code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
import logging
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello csdfwe!"

@app.route('/test/')
def check():
    return render_template('template.html')

@app.route('/result/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    print "*****", request.form, "******"
    return render_template('template1.html')

@app.route('/result1/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def result1():
    return "Pressed OK"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`template1.html` is

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "{{ url_for('result') }}" method = "POST">
         <p>Value1 <input type = "text" name = "Value1"  /></p>            
         <p>Value2<input type ="text" name = "Value2" /></p>
         <p>Charging Duration <input type ="text" name = "Charging_Duration" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit" /></p>
      </form> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Query : In html file, as you can see I am having different text box for Value1 and Value2. I want to print the existing value of value1 that is already there after the text box. It means template will show the already existing value and user can set any new value. I don't know how to get the value from a function in html.

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

[`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.render_template) takes context variables that will be available in the template. You can pass any number of variables to the template.

So, try something like this:

in your route code:

```
@app.route('/result/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    value1 = request.form.get('Value1')
    return render_template('template1.html', value1=value1)
```

template1.html:

```
<html>
   <body>
      Value1 is {{value1 or 'not set'}}
      <form action = "{{ url_for('result') }}" method = "POST">
         <p>Value1 <input type = "text" name = "Value1" /></p>
         <p>Value2<input type ="text" name = "Value2" /></p>
         <p>Charging Duration <input type ="text" name = "Charging_Duration" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" name = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```